# ASP MVC 3 hiddenfield postback behavior

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have ASP MVC 3 application,

In my model I have IsGoodMode bool property.

and using this property like `<%: Html.HiddenFor(m => m.IsGoodMode)%>` on my View

When I open page first time my `IsGoodMode` contains `false` value. 
I change `IsGoodMode` value from `false` to `true` in javascript.
I press submit button and controller getting model with `IsGoodMode` contain true value.

in controller I change `IsGoodMode` to `false`;

But on view page IsGoodMode still have true value.

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(SettingsModel model)
        {                                
            model.IsGoodMode = false;
            return View(model);
        }
```

Why this is happens? 
How MVC3 binding properties after post back ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to replicate the same behavior in my local. I feel that there is something crazy happening with Html.HiddenFor() helper method. I got the functionality working by using slightly different approaches.

Approach : 1

- Replace Html.HiddenFor() with regular html hidden input element. I used the following markup and it worked :

  ```
  <input type="hidden" value="<%= Model.IsActive %>" />
  ```

Approach : 2

- Used alternate syntax for Html.HiddenFor(). Given below :

> ```
>       <%= Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.IsActive) %>
> ```

You can try either of the two approaches and my guess is it should work for you too.

Comment: yes approach 1 working,  but this case I can't send value to model. Approach : 2 is working with "bug" as well.

Comment: For approach one to work, you will have to add the "name" attribute. In your case the deceleration will look like :<input type="hidden" name="IsGoodMode" value="<%= Model.IsGoodMode %>" />. Note that the name property should match exactly with the name of the property.

Answer (score 2):

The MSDN article on [ModelState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstate.aspx) is brief, to say the least, but it's ModelState that is responsible for this.

Once @Html.BeginForm() is processed, the controls are populated by the values from ModelState of the current model, if it's applicable.

You can override this behavior by calling ModelState.Clear() in your action method.

Comment: @cleric is talking about initializing hidden fields, I don't see any textboxes in the question.

Comment: Let him use ModelState.Clear() and counter back. I have edited and removed the textbox from the reference. But, I assume the model binding is the reason this is happening